# What's an easy way to clad timber frame wall so as to be weatherproof?

Tags: walls, roof, timber-framing, weather-resistant

I have recently done a repair to the back wall of my ruin of a garage and it is topped with a 2ft timber frame (5 meters long) which I will clad in plywood and then attempt to weatherproof. No one much sees it as it will be facing the end of a neighbours very long garden. Can I just pin roofing felt down the 2ft height so it drips free of the block wall below? I would like it to last a good while as access is awkward. The prevailing winds tend to blow the rain clear of this wall as its roughly north facing in London.
  What would be the simplest way to weatherproof this wall bearing in mind that I will be up a ladder and working on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paint the plywood before you install it, and afterwards paint the nails.

You can probably paint the nails with a small roller on an extension handle instead of using the ladder.

Consider using fibre-cement (eg Hardieflex) instead of plywood.

Comment: Painting ahead of time will work and extend the life of the plywood.

Answer (score 0):

Shiplap is designed to shed water ie overlapping planks.

Comment: @Jasen.  Well, painted plywood would certainly be the easiest method but not sure how long it would last bearing in mind the quality of plywood these days. Also like the idea of cement board which I'd forgotten about - might go for that. I consider that answered,  Thanks.